# MongoDB find after aggregation in Graphql

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I want to find the document with the latest datetime value.

I plan is to use aggregation to find the latest datetime. Then use the value of datetime to find the list of documents.

This is my resolver function:

```
propertys_for_sell_latest:{
            type: new GraphQLList(sellType),
            args:{},
            resolve(parent, args){
                sell.aggregate([
                    {$project:{_id:0,DateTime:1}},
                    {$sort:{DateTime:-1}},
                    {$limit:1}
                ]).exec((err, latest) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(latest[0])
                    sell.find(latest[0])
                })

            }
        }
```

The result is none.

I am very new to Graphql and Javascript. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I can create two functions using async and await.

```
async function getLatestDate(model){
    const latest = await model.aggregate([
        {$project:{_id:0,DateTime:1}},
        {$sort:{DateTime:-1}},
        {$limit:1}
    ])
    return latest[0]
}

async function propertys_latest(model){
    const result = await getLatestDate(model)
    return model.find(result)
    }
```

Then use it in the root query

```
propertys_for_sell_latest:{
        type: new GraphQLList(sellType),
        args:{},
        resolve:(parent, args) => propertys_latest(sell)
    }
```

Actually, I am not too sure about the reason.